# Python: How to add specific character as transforming a list to a string in differentiating the last item in the list?

Tags: python

I want to transform a list to a string including the square brackets and comma and then concatenate with another string.

```
Input:
    list1 = [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]
    str1 = 'is a list.\n'

Expected output:
    [1, 4, 3, 2, 5] is a list.
```

What I'm trying is like this:

```
path = [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]
str1 = 'is a list.\n'
ss = '['
for item in path:
    ss += str(item) + ', '
ss += '] ' + str1
print(ss)
```

But this results in the following output:

```
[1, 4, 3, 2, 5, ] is a list.
```

How to prevent the last comma ',' from generating as the process of transform?

I'm considering to take a specific process based on whether the item is the last one in the list.

But how can I know it?

Or else is there any other solution?

Really appreciate!

Comment: This is not needed. Try to print the result of `str(path)`

Comment: Your expected output also has the trialing comma.

Comment: Yup, your desired output looks a lot like your actual output.

Comment: If you insist on doing this manually, then the [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method might help you... i.e. `ss += ', '.join(str(item) for item in path)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Has corrected.

Comment: To do so, use the string `join` function.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is bad Approah:

```
path = [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]
str1 = 'is a list.\n'
ss = '['
for i in range(len(Path)):
    if i != (len(path)-1):
        ss += str(path[i]) + ', '
    else:
        ss += str(path[i])
ss += '] ' + str1
print(ss)
```

A good Approach is using f-Strings.

```
print(f"{path} is a list.\n")
```

if u doesn't like f-strings then

```
print("{} is a list.\n".format(path))
```

Comment: This is bad. Concatenating strings with `+` or `+=` is a bad approach and should be avoided at all costs. Not even saying the solution uses multiple anti-patterns.

Comment: Yes, I know it.

Comment: The reason that I want this implementation is that there is a need to format this ouput in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Print function uses the `__str__` or `__repr__` magic method of objects to render them. Knowing that you can do either:

```py
print(path, "is a list.")
```

Or with string formatting:

```py
print(f"{path} is a list.")
```

Comment: Sorry did this with my phone and shortcutted, I've edited the answer.

Comment: `print` actually uses `__str__`, which falls back to `__repr__` in case it is not implemented...